# Visual Studio 2019: CMake Generation Seems to be Stuck, CMakeLists.txt is still parsing

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build an existing CMake project with VS 2019 Professional, and when I open the folder through VS, after a few seconds it says in the Output window that the CMake generation finished. However, when I switch to CMake Targets view in the Solution Explorer, it says that the CMakeLists.txt is still parsing..., and in the Project menu Generate Cache is greyed out but Cancel CMake Cache Generation can be selected (which doesn't seem to do anything" and also Delete Cache is greyed out. This makes me think that either VS doesn't think the CMake generation is done, or it's actually stuck somewhere.

Because of that I can't Build (no option under Build) and I can't Select a Startup Item/Target. I've searched and seen this issue a couple of times but there wasn't any answers/solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like updating my VS2019 solved that issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).